# How to create a function in views which can be called from templates, with or without arguments?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a function which displays the live location of a vehicle on demand. There are two functions and thus buttons, when clicked should run a code internally, and display the result on this same view/page. I am not able to understand how to create those two functions,  without reloading my page or going to another page. I do not have to pass any kind of arguments in the function from the template, as of now. Is this possible in django??

---

### Code

Here is my function in my view.py

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class QuizResultsView(DetailView):
    model = Quiz
    context_object_name = 'quiz'
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/quiz_results.html'
    tripId = str()

    def start_trip(self):
        quiz = self.get_object()
        lr_object = get_object_or_404(LR, lr_quiz=quiz.id)
        # ----------Call api to fetch location code -----------#
```

My api fetch code will return a json object which I have to parse and enter the same in a Google Iframe, and it takes about 2-3 seconds to populate the iframe.

I have many 'mini-functions' or whatever they are called in my same function, just like :

```
def get_queryset (self):
    return self.request.user.quizzes.all()
```

Hence, is there a way to create more functions just like these? Also, how will I call such functions from my templates? Is there any other way of creating a view, where I can have multiple buttons, with individual functions to each button, and it does not reload the page or go to any other page ?

### Complete Code

```
def start_trip (self):
    quiz = self.get_object()

    lr_object = get_object_or_404(LR, lr_quiz=quiz.id)
    print("@271 lr_object.driver_name", lr_object.driver_name)

    gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=###)

    driver_num = lr_object.driver_name

    origin = lr_object.lr_consignee_address  # origin from lR
    dest = lr_object.lr_consignor_address  # dest from LR
    geocode_result_orig = gmaps.geocode(origin)
    geocode_result_orig = gmaps.geocode(origin)

    lat_orig = str(geocode_result_orig[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"])
    lon_orig = str(geocode_result_orig[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])

    geocode_result_dest = gmaps.geocode(dest)

    lat_dest = str(geocode_result_dest[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"])
    lon_dest = str(geocode_result_dest[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])

    url = 'https://sct.intutrack.com/api/prod/trips/start'
    payload = 'tel=' + driver_num + '&src=' + lat_orig + '%2C%20' + lon_orig + '&dest=' + lat_dest + '%2C%20' + lon_dest + '&srcname=Intugine' \
                                                                                                                           '%20Technologies&destname=Bangalore&client=XYZ&vendor=Rivigo&vehicle=' \
                                                                                                                           'MH01x123&invoice=123ZXYZ&eta_hrs=75'

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    username = '###'
    password = '###'
    user_pass = (username, password)

    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=user_pass)

    response = response.json()
    tripId = response["tripId"]
```

**UPDATE:**
I am thinking this can only be done with javascript, so I guess my question becomes *'How to pass django variables to a javascript function (without reloading the page ofc.)?'*

Comment: Consider the use of javascript to call these functions and retrieve the results.

Comment: In fact JS is the *only* way to do this. If you want to have a button that triggers an action in a view, but you don't want your page to reload, the only possible thing to do is to use JS.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hey, but I do have some parameters I have to call in my javascript function (e.g. quiz.id or quiz.subject). Is there any example where somebody has done something similar to this ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. JS doesn't know anything about Django variables, nor does it need to. Whatever data you want to pass must be in the page already, either in the URL or the DOM.

Comment: Can I create a function like `trackNow( {{ quiz.pk }})` and pass my variables like this? I am really doubting this ._. @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman Does that mean I cannot create a JS function which can somehow be passed values from the view as DOM ?

Comment: Of course you can (to both questions).